# Private fields not able to access in draft mode

Tags: entities, files, users, nodes

Private fields attached to old revisions are not accessible to download when the new revision(Latest revision) of the node is in draft.

How to make it to download the files.

Comment: Which contributed modules are you using for such "private fields" (if any)?